# AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: python, django, filefield, django-file-upload

I have a DjangoFileField in my model. I am trying to convert the type of the audio from that FielField to mp3 and then again trying to save it. But after converting the type and exporting it using pydub it is returning the following error

```
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

My code is like this

```
def get_from_function(AudioSegment, format):

    form = "from_{0}".format(format)
    print form
    if hasattr(AudioSegment, form):
        return getattr(AudioSegment, form)
    return None


    audio = request.FILES.get('audio', None)
    if audio:
        name_list = audio.name.rsplit(".")
        voice_format =name_list[1]
        from_format = get_from_function(AudioSegment, voice_format)
        if from_format and callable(from_format):
            sound = from_format(audio)
            audio = sound.export("media/{0}".format(name_list[0]), mp3")
```

when i print the `audio` it prints

```
<open file 'media/barsandtone', mode 'wb+' at 0x7f771e5e2f60>
```

and when i print the type of file it prints

```
<type 'file'>
```

but when i assign the audio field to django model like

```
Mymodel.objects.create(audio=audio)
```

it gives error

```
AttributeError at /create/
'file' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

What is the correct way to save the exported file into django model

Answer (score 7):

django needs a `ContentFile` usually to do this passing it a stream of data, and it doesn't work the way you usually pass arguments to a model. The proper way to do this is the following

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
[...]
mymodel = Mymodel()
mymodel.audio.save(audio.name, ContentFile(audio.read()))
```

don't forget to pass the stream to ContentFile. Django won't raise any errors if you pass it `ContentFile(audio)` but in that case you won't save the file content..

Answer (score 6):

I got same error that is solved now i would suggest you to open that file in read mode then save it. here is my code :

```
from django.core.files import File as DjangoFile
file_obj1 = DjangoFile(open(file_name, mode='rb'), name=file_name)
File.objects.create(title=file_name, file=file_obj1, content_object=task_obj, author=task_obj.client)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was creating a django form with some FileFields for which I wanted to show the currently existing file from a model's instance. I'm leaving this answer here in case anyone else end up here for similar reasons, even though I know that this answer doesn't apply to the OP's situation.

Normally you would bound the form and the model but in this case it's not possible for reasons a bit long to explain, so I wanted to query the model to obtain the File field and make it be the initial data.

It reached a point where I managed to make it work until the view can render the field and the currently existing field (as it's normally rendered by the ClearableFileInput widget).

That point was reached by filling `self.fields["field_name"].initial` with either:

- Using a `DummyFile` class:

```py
class DummyFile:
    def __init__(self, url, name):
        self.url = url
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

- Filling it with the existing instance, like

```py
self.fields[field_name].initial = doc.file.instance
self.fields[field_name].initial.url = doc.file.url
```

But then in both cases the `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_committed'` was raised when uploading a file, although it was correctly uploaded and saved.

## Solution

Turned out that it behaves different when you assign the initial data for a field by using `self.fields[field_name].initial` than using `self.initial[field_name]`, and doing it like this worked like a charm:

```py
doc = Document.objects.filter(
    filters_to_locate_the_model_instance=this_and_that,
).first()
if doc:
    self.initial[field_name] = doc.file
```

The HTML is rendered with the link to the existing file, it loads fine if there is not an existing file, and uploads and saves a file without any error.